# .Net 5 - API JsonProperty

Tags: api, .net-core

I have a [HttpPost] function in API Controller, that has this definition:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] TestData testData)
```

I tried to use many atributes anotations in my class TestData [JsonProperty("")], [JsonPropertyName("")], [JsonObject].
I used libraries - Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json.Serialization. But the testData always included null. The API works when I put a body with same name of atribute has. Soo I expect, I am missing something in my Configuration.
I even try to add `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson()` . Nothing changed.
How does it make it work in .Net 5 ?

Comment: Hi @Mrnin, please share your model and how do you post the data?

Comment: Hi @jps, I was succesfully sended my data to another API. Soo I think, my HttpPost process from a mobile phone works correctly. Do u think, if I use [JsonPropertyName("")] up on my properties, all should work automaticly without aditional changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, There was an issue with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

@jps

```
public class TestData
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("test_number")]
        public long Number { get; set; }

        ...
   }
```

- When I post a body {"test_number":"123456"} on http://.../Test . I see testData.Number = null
- I feels like, the JsonPropertyName works only for Serialization , and not for
  Deserialization

Comment: JsonPropertyName attr was what I was after. Thanks